# MouseOver MouseOut issue in Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, dom-events

This is a strange one, I'm shocked I've never noticed it before. It works like this, if your mouse is still and a div programmatically moves underneath your mouse, a `mouseover` event will not be triggered in Chrome/Safari - same goes for `mouseout`. Of course, if you move your mouse slightly once the div has moved underneath your mouse it will work as expected.

I created a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZWbn/). Just let the div oscillate under your mouse, works fine in Firefox, not in Chrome or Safari - have yet to test in IE.

I'm leaning toward this solution... basically rolling my own `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events using this:

```
if (mouseX > divLeft && mouseX < divRight &&
    mouseY > divTop && mouseY < divBottom){
    // mouse is inside div
}
```

*I say `mouseenter` and leave because this method would have no bubbling*

I was wondering if anyone else had thoughts about this... I have a feeling there is an easy way around it, but so far google hasn't turned anything up.

Comment: Just checked - IE 7 does not trigger the `mouseover` or `mouseout` when the mouse is still.

Comment: +1, pretty interesting. It might be possible to trigger the event with javascript by checking the position of the mouse as the div moves.

Comment: cool thanks, I was just firing up VirtualBox to test

Comment: yes JCOC611 that is definitely possible I put the basic conditional you would need to do so in the post... I may resort to that, just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: +1 That is really interesting. I guess its that Webkit does not see the mouse leaving the object, but the object leaving the mouse. We must be in Soviet Russia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4117

You might find this bug interesting.

Comment: very cool. I guess its just a bug then... I'm going to a wait a bit to see if there are any other solutions but I'm pretty sure that I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Looks like there's no way around this one other than the technique I mentioned in my original question - I just used that and it works fine for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to continue happening on Safari. The workaround I went for is using css . Even if the `mouseover` won't be triggered, the `:hover` or `:not(:hover)` css pseudo elements work. So, in case that what you want to do on hover is aplicable through css, like hiding/showing an element, this is a posible solution.

Comment: interesting - I tried it but it still doesn't work with the jsfiddle I posted (all those years ago :D)