# How to detect "mouseout" directly after "dragend" using D3.js in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent, dom-events, mouseout

I am trying to detect whether the mouse is still over an SVG circle after the circle had been dragged and moved in a function bound to the `dragend` event. I created this [example](https://blockbuilder.org/delenamalan/3ad7c010763e32d4e22a81556a01a4e3) to demonstrate the issue.

In Firefox, the `mouseout` event is triggered immediately after the `dragend` if the mouse isn't over the circle anymore, but in Chrome the `mouseout` event is only triggered after the mouse has been moved after the `dragend` event.

I even tried to manually trigger a `mousemove` on the `document` at the end of `dragend`, but it still doesn't detect a `mouseout`.

Is there any way in which to force Chrome to check if the mouse is now out of the circle immediately after `dragend`? Or is the only way around this to manually check if the coordinates of the mouse coincide with the area the circle covers or not at the end of `dragend`?

Update: I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809971/mouseover-mouseout-issue-in-safari-chrome?rq=1) related question and it seems my problem is caused by a Webkit [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4117).

Update: not reproducible in later versions of Chrome. Seems to have been fixed between Chrome version 61 and 62. Attaching a video of the bug in macOS Sierra Chrome version 61:

[image: macOS Sierra Chrome 61 bug]

macOS Sierra Chrome 62 no bug:

[image: macOS Sierra Chrome 62 no bug]

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have? It seems to be working the same for me in both FF and Chrome. I'm on version `43.0.2357.132 m`. On a side note, if you are dragging and move the mouse very quickly it can also trigger a `mouseout` event. Could potentially cause buggy behaviour in the future.

Comment: I'm also using `43.0.2357.132`

Comment: Side note: In the specifications of the UI events in [DOM 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents) and [DOM 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#event-type-mouseout) this was the expected behavior: *"The mouseout event occurs when the pointing device is moved away from an element."* Until this definition was moved to the standalone [UI Events](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-mouseout) specification there was no mentioning of dispatching if the element was moved away from the pointer instead of vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Call [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) and see what the mouse is over yourself.